# loadInPlaceFileRepresentation vs loadFileRepresentation

Tags: swift, file-upload, avmutablecomposition

I have an app where users upload videos and then I create clips from the video using AVMutableComposition. I don't fully understand the difference between loadInPlaceFileRepresentation and loadFileRepresentation. Is there any reason I can't always use loadInPlaceFileRepresentation as it doesn't copy the file to my app and loads incredibly faster?